# Running another script while sharing functions and variable as in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, share

I have a notebook that `%run` another notebook under JupyterLab. They can call back and forth each other functions and share some global variables.
I now want to convert the notebooks to py files so it can be executed from the command line.

I follow the advice found on SO and imported the 2nd file into the main one.
However, I found out that they can not call each other functions. This is a major problem because the 2nd file is a service to the main one, but it uses continuously functions that are part of the main one.

Essentially, the second program is non-GUI and it is driven by the main one which is a GUI program. Thus whenever the service program needs to print, it checks to see if a flag is set that tells it that it runs in a GUI mode, and then instead of simple printing it calls a function in the main one which knows how to display it on the GUI screen. I want to keep this separation.

How can I achieve it without too much change to the service program?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up collecting all the GUI functions from the main GUI program, and putting them into a 3rd file in a class, including the relevant variables.
In the GUI program, just before calling the non GUI program (the service one) I created the class and set all the variables, and in the call I passed the class.
Then in the service program I call the functions that are in the class and got the variables needed from the class as well.
The changes to the service program were minor - just reading the variables from the class and change the calls to the GUI function to call the class functions instead.